# Fade loop problems with arduino

Tags: loops, arduino, rgb, led

I'm trying a synchronize an RGB strip with color wipes on a strand of WS2812 LEDs. I need for the fade function to check the previous state of each color, and decide whether to fade up, fade down, or do nothing as the next color comes in. For example, the red RGB would fade up with the red color wipe. For the purple wipe, the blue would fade in, but the red RGB, already lit, would remain lit instead of starting over at zero and fading in again.

I've tried using case statements, else/if statements and various operators, but still cant seem to get it right. The Arduino forums and Adafruit forums didn't seem to have any answers either. Below is my latest attempt. I'm open to any help, or even a whole new approach if anyone has a better idea! Thanks!

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

#define PINA 7    //ws2812 strip a
#define PINB 8    //ws2812 strip b
#define REDPIN 6   //RGB red
#define GREENPIN 5  //RGB green
#define BLUEPIN 3    //RGB blue
#define FADESPEED 5     // make this higher to slow down
#define NUMPIX 26  // number of pixels

// Parameter 1 = number of pixels in strip
// Parameter 2 = pin number (most are valid)
// Parameter 3 = pixel type flags, add together as needed:
//   NEO_KHZ800  800 KHz bitstream (most NeoPixel products w/WS2812 LEDs)
 //   NEO_KHZ400  400 KHz (classic 'v1' (not v2) FLORA pixels, WS2811 drivers)
//   NEO_GRB     Pixels are wired for GRB bitstream (most NeoPixel products)
//   NEO_RGB     Pixels are wired for RGB bitstream (v1 FLORA pixels, not v2)

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip_a = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIX, PINA, NEO_RGB + NEO_KHZ800);
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip_b = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIX, PINB, NEO_RGB + NEO_KHZ800);

int oldRed;      //previous RGB red value
int oldGreen;    //previous RGB green value
int oldBlue;    //previous RGB blue value

void setup() {
  pinMode(REDPIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GREENPIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BLUEPIN, OUTPUT);
  strip_a.begin();
  strip_a.show();     // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
  strip_b.begin();
  strip_b.show();     // Initialize all pixels to 'off'  
  analogWrite(BLUEPIN, 0);     // Initialize RGB strip to 'off'  
  analogWrite(GREENPIN, 0);
  analogWrite(REDPIN, 0);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  oldRed = 0;    //Set initial RGB values to 0
  oldGreen = 0;
  oldBlue = 0;
}

void loop()
{ 

  colorWipe(255,0,0);  //wipe to red
  delay(2500);
  colorWipe(0,255,0); // wipe to green
  delay(2500);
  colorWipe(0,0,255); // wipe to blue
  delay(2500);
  colorWipe(255,255,255); // wipe to white
  delay(2500);
  colorWipe(0,0,0);  // fade to black
  delay(2500);
      }
    void colorWipe(int r,int g, int b){

    for(int x = 0; x < NUMPIX; x++){      //incriment counter
    strip_a.setPixelColor(x, r,g,b);      //turn on pixel
    strip_b.setPixelColor(x, r,g,b); 

    Serial.println(x);



    if (r==0 && oldRed==255){                    // if new value is 0 and old value is 255
      int newRed = 255-(x*(255/NUMPIX));        // fade out in as many increments as there are pixels
      analogWrite(REDPIN,newRed);
      if(x = NUMPIX){                           // if all cycles are complete
        oldRed = 0;                              //reset old value to 0
        analogWrite(REDPIN, 0);                //make sure lights are completly off
      }         
    }
    if(r==255 && oldRed==0){
      int newRed = x*(255/NUMPIX);
      analogWrite(REDPIN, newRed);
      if(x = NUMPIX) {
        oldRed = 255;
        analogWrite(REDPIN, 255);

      }
    }




    /*   if (r > oldRed){                    // new value greater than old (fade on)
     int newRed = x*(;        // add another incriment to new red value
     analogWrite(REDPIN,newRed);
     oldRed=newRed;                    //reset old value to 255
     }
     if (r < oldRed);   {           // new value less than old (fade off)
     int newRed=255-(x*10);      // subtract another incriment from new red value
     analogWrite(REDPIN, newRed);  //fade red out
     oldRed=newRed;                    //reset old value to 0
     }
     */
    /*
    if (g >oldGreen){                    // new value greater than old (fade on)
     int newGreen = x*(255/NUMPIX);        // add another incriment to new green value
     analogWrite(GREENPIN,newGreen);
     oldGreen=newGreen;                    //reset old value to 255
     }
     if (g < oldGreen);
     {           // new value less than old (fade off)
     int newGreen=255-(x*(255/NUMPIX));      // subtract another incriment from new Green value
     analogWrite(GREENPIN, newGreen);  //fade Green out
     oldGreen=newGreen;                    //reset old value to 0
     }

     if (b > oldBlue){                    // new value greater than old (fade on)
     int newBlue = x*(255/NUMPIX);        // add another incriment to new Blue value
     analogWrite(BLUEPIN,newBlue);
     oldBlue=newBlue;                    //reset old value to 255
     }
     else (b < oldBlue);
     {           // new value less than old (fade off)
     int newBlue=255-(x*(255/NUMPIX));      // subtract another incriment from new Blue value
     analogWrite(BLUEPIN, newBlue);  //fade Blue out
     oldBlue=newBlue;                    //reset old value to 0
     }

     */
    delay(100);
    strip_a.show();
    strip_b.show();
  }
}
```